# Meteor/Blaze Print Object as JSON

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

All,

I have on object in Meteor/Blaze. I tried this.

```
{{data}}
```

And it output

```
[object Object]
```

Is there any way I can get it to output JSON instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to print a JSON object in JSON format in your Blaze view, you might wanna look at `JSON.stringify()` method.

**Home.js [Helper example]**

```
import './Home.html';

Template.home.helpers({
  jsonPrint(jsonObject) { // with Latest Javascript ECMAScript 2015+
    return JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
  }
})
```

**Home.html [Your Blaze view]**

```
<template name="home">
    <body>
        <p>
          JSON output:
        </p>
        <div class="code">
          {{jsonPrint yourJsonObject}}
        </div>
    </body>
</template>
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

I actually use a dev helper defined as below and which is in my own [prototyping boilerplate](https://github.com/robertdavid010/meteor_boilerplate/blob/master/client/lib/helpers/genericHelpers.js):

```
Template.registerHelper("toJSON", function (object) {
  return object ? JSON.stringify(object, null, 2) : null;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to return values in that object, you will need to use JS dot notation so

`{{foo.bar}}`

where